# Ubuntu hangs on boot after blackout- Detect the available GPUs

Tags: boot, gpu, detect

Please help me, its my workstation.
It worked fine until a power blackout. Since then it doesn't boot anymore. (two times it started to the login screen, but with ENTER or a mouse click he login screen dissappeared and the screen remained black.

[image]

After that Ubuntu (eOS) doesn't boot further

Update:
looked in the last_gfx_boot -> its empty
syslog is here -> [link to my syslog](http://www.thaler-online.com/syslog.txt)

Which steps should/could I try next?

Thanks,
Florian

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem in the following way:

1. Boot in recovery mode with read/write access
2. Go to shell as root
3. sudo apt-get remove lightdm (now gdm3 is default)
4. Start the network: sudo service network-manager restart
5. sudo apt upgrade
6. reboot

For me that worked.
Can be that it would have even worked if I didn't remove lightdm.

Answer (score 2):

I just had to boot into recovery mode and run `update-grub` to repair the system after a similar error.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this as well with an old laptop. We have a custom Ubuntu 12.04 that we install in several notebooks and most of the time works ok, it's the same ubuntu for every laptop but in one of those this happened.

I went to a console (CTRL+F1) and started X with the command `startx`, because that worked I tried creating a X file and that solved the issue:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
    FontPath     "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "glx"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor0"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "Accel"                 # [<bool>]
        #Option     "AccelMethod"           # <str>
        #Option     "Backlight"             # <str>
        #Option     "CustomEDID"            # <str>
        #Option     "DRI"                   # <str>
        #Option     "Present"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ColorKey"              # <i>
        #Option     "VideoKey"              # <i>
        #Option     "Tiling"                # [<bool>]
        #Option     "LinearFramebuffer"     # [<bool>]
        #Option     "HWRotation"            # [<bool>]
        #Option     "VSync"                 # [<bool>]
        #Option     "PageFlip"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "SwapbuffersWait"       # [<bool>]
        #Option     "TripleBuffer"          # [<bool>]
        #Option     "XvPreferOverlay"       # [<bool>]
        #Option     "HotPlug"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ReprobeOutputs"        # [<bool>]
        #Option     "XvMC"                  # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ZaphodHeads"           # <str>
        #Option     "VirtualHeads"          # <i>
        #Option     "TearFree"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "PerCrtcPixmaps"        # [<bool>]
        #Option     "FallbackDebug"         # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DebugFlushBatches"     # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DebugFlushCaches"      # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DebugWait"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "BufferCache"           # [<bool>]
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "intel"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "Card0"
    Monitor    "Monitor0"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

EDIT (2 months later) I had a similar problem again... xhost unable to open """

I've reinstalled xorg and it worked

EDIT (2 days later) I found that deleting temporary files of xorg and lightdm solves the problem [I've detailed everything here](http://migueleonardortiz.com.ar/linux/lightdm-linux/failed-to-start-light-display-manager/1741).